# C# Console application crashing before if statement can run

Tags: c#

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("1. SHC ");
        int UserInput1 = Console.Read();

        if (UserInput1 == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mass (kg): ");
            int shcmass = Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine("Specific Heat Capactiy (J/Kg/°C): ");
            int shcshc = Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine("Temperature Difference (△Ø): ");
            int shctemp = Console.Read();

            int shcfinal = shcmass * shcshc * shctemp;

            Console.WriteLine("Energy: " + shcfinal);
        }
```

This is the code I am using within a small console application. I don't know if I am missing something but every time I run it, the first bit works where it says "1. SHC" and gives time for the user input. But once entered the console application dies and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: `Console.Read()` does not return a number that the user types in, it returns an integer version of a `char`. It will never equal `1`. Please tell us what error you are getting, in detail, and what line it appears on.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing stopping the console application to close, add a Console.ReadLine() at the end of your mainloop.  I'd recommend using ReadLine() over reads for other input as well, but it would depend on your needs.  If you see from the "Remarks" section of the [Console.Read documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx) it's preferable to use ReadLine()

e.g.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine("1. SHC ");
    int UserInput1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (UserInput1 == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Mass (kg): ");
        int shcmass = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Specific Heat Capactiy (J/Kg/°C): ");
        int shcshc = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Temperature Difference (△Ø): ");
        int shctemp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int shcfinal = shcmass * shcshc * shctemp;

        Console.WriteLine("Energy: " + shcfinal);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: `int UserInput1 = Console.ReadLine();` will give a compilation error about type conversions.

Comment: Okay those are wrapped with int.Parse(), it would be best to add logic to handle the potential exceptions that could result from the int.Parse call.

Answer (score 0):

`Console.Read()` returns

> The next character from the input stream, or negative one (-1) if
>   there are currently no more characters to be read.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx

You will need

```
ch = Convert.ToChar(x);
```

Excerpt:

```
class Sample 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
    string m1 = "\nType a string of text then press Enter. " +
                "Type '+' anywhere in the text to quit:\n";
    string m2 = "Character '{0}' is hexadecimal 0x{1:x4}.";
    string m3 = "Character     is hexadecimal 0x{0:x4}.";
    char ch;
    int x;
//
    Console.WriteLine(m1);
    do  
        {
        x = Console.Read();
        try 
            {
            ch = Convert.ToChar(x);
            if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(ch))
               {
               Console.WriteLine(m3, x);
               if (ch == 0x0a) 
                   Console.WriteLine(m1);
               }
            else
               Console.WriteLine(m2, ch, x);
            }
        catch (OverflowException e) 
            {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Value read = {1}.", e.Message, x);
            ch = Char.MinValue;
            Console.WriteLine(m1);
            }
        } while (ch != '+');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've had similar issues before. When using `Console.Read()` after `Console.WriteLine()` you'll end up reading '\r' which is what causes the crash I believe. Try using `Console.ReadKey()` instead.

Comment: ReadKey() seems to create another error. I previously tried ReadKey() but it doesn't seem to like int ........ = Console.ReadKey(); and I need them to be int for the equation.

Comment: [Look at the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx), ReadKey() returns a struct, you can just use `int Userinput1 = (int)Console.ReadKey().KeyChar`

Comment: Well, if you want the character '1' to be read as an int of value 1 you'd use a parse method instead of a typecast